# Add Line items button is not showing up on contract line items in lightning

Tags: lightning

How can we enable add contract line items button in lightning.In classic i am able to see the button but in lightning it is not showing up.Any help will be much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Have you added the New Line items button on the related list on service Contract page layout? There are two separate buttons for classic and lightning. In classic, it is called Add line item and in Lightning it is called New line Items.

Comment: Yes i added both the buttons in related list.

Comment: Can you check your Contract line item related list then?

Comment: Added my comments as answer. You can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The button is available in both classic and Lightning. Their is little
>   difference in their name. In classic, it is called Add line item and
>   in Lightning it is called New line Items.

On service Contract page, you need to add both the buttons on the layout for contract line item related list.

To check the button, you need to look into related list on the service contract record page.